# Using FormData for casper file upload

Tags: javascript, post, casperjs, multipartform-data, form-data

This is my code:

```
var content = fs.read('test/test.png');
var formData = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob([content], {type:'image/png'});
formData.append('picture',blob);
require('utils').dump(formData);

this.open("http://localhost:8080/dns_capcha", {
    headers:{
      'Content-type':'image/png'
    },
    method: 'post',
    data:formData
});
```

With this code I am getting this error:

```
CasperError: open(): invalid request settings data value: [object FormData]
```

Could somebody tell my what I have done wrong in this code?

Comment: typo on `headres : {`

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Line 8 on the above code. Shouldn't it be headers instead of headres?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't  notice.